# SQL Oracle Create View Error in finding most recent owner of property

Tags: sql, oracle, date, view

So I'm working on a view for a database. In this view it needs to show all of the properties that a person owns and only show the current owner of the property. The way it's supposed to be done is by looking at the purchase date for a propertyID and only show the most recent one.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
CREATE VIEW P_OWNERS_AND_PROPERTIES_V AS
SELECT P_OWNER.OWNERID, P_OWNER.LNAME, P_OWNER.FNAME, 
P_PURCHASE.PROPERTYID,P_PURCHASE.PURCHASEDATE
FROM P_OWNER LEFT JOIN P_PURCHASE
ON P_OWNER.OWNERID=P_PURCHASE.OWNERID
WHERE (P_PURCHASE.PURCHASEDATE = (SELECT MAX(P1.PURCHASEDATE) 
FROM P_PURCHASE P1 WHERE P1.OWNERID = P_PURCHASE.OWNERID)) 
OR (P_PURCHASE.PROPERTYID IS NULL);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: Cleaning up code.

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: No error so to speak. The results displayed are wrong. There are two of the same properties listed as owned by separate people, when it is only currently owned by one. I only want to display the one with the latest purchasedate.

Comment: I gave this a try and I'm having trouble with the left join. I interpreted your left join as you wanting to include owners who don't own a property. Do you want to do that, or do you only want owners who actually own properties?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

Join p_owner and p_purchase via ownerid. This gives you a list where each owner is shown with the all the properties ever owned (i.e. a full listing of all purchases)

Then you add an analytic function rownum() where you partition by propteryid and order by purchasedate desc. This adds a number to each row, such that the latest purchase for each property gets a rownum()=1. Alias this column with something like "purchase_rank".

Purchase_rank tells you, for each purchase, if it was the latest, second-to-latest etc.

Then wrap the whole thing in another select, where you filter "where purchase_rank=1", and chose the columns you want to see.

In any case, don't shy away from analytic functions. They can be life-saving.